# Hibernate 5 : can't find config file

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, hibernate-5.x

I'm discovering Hibernate today, and I'm struggling while trying to make a minimal program find my "hibernate.cfg.xml" configuration file.

Here is what I already tried :

My main :

```
package testHibernate;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    }
}
```

at the same level of this main file :

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pianissimo</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">nx5fDdVdEGVDS6Tq</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)
Sincerely,
Alann

Comment: What you actually want to do ?

Comment: Try one level higher, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put `hibernate.cfg.xml` on the same level as your `Main` class. You should put it on the same level as your `testHibernate` package, in the root of the source folder. Or you need to specify a path to `hibernate.cfg.xml` like this

```
Configuration configuration = 
    new Configuration().configure("/testHibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```